# Use $\alpha$ to write a basis for $K$ over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Consider the Field $F = \mathbb{Z}_3$ and let $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1 \in F[x]$.
>
> We assume known that $K = F(\alpha)$, for $\alpha = x + f(x) \in K$. Use $\alpha$ to write a basis for $K$ over $F$. Express $\alpha^6$ and $\alpha^4$ in this basis.

I get the basis $\left(1, \alpha, \alpha^2\right)$. And then to express $\alpha^4$ and $\alpha^6$ I get:

$$\alpha^4 = \alpha^2 +  1 - \alpha$$
$$\alpha^6 = \alpha^4 + \alpha^2 - \alpha^3$$

Is this correct?

Comment: PSA: Please use one of these: $\mathbb F_3,\mathbb Z/(3), \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ for field with $3$ elements, hurts to see $\mathbb Z_3$(it is used for 3-adiacs too!). Anyways how did you get the result you have?(it isn't correct)

Comment: The Z_3 was the one used in the book, so I did the same. Sorry for any inconvenience I've created. It means Integer space Z.

Comment: I think I misread. Is a basis of (1, \alpha^2) correct?

Comment: the basis $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ is indeed a basis(why?). Btw use \$ for latex code

Comment: I was thinking that (1, x, $x^2$) would span the entire space of the field. Then I would just multiply with $\alpha$, which I now believe I multiplied by wrong equation.

Comment: Maybe something simpler: What is $\alpha^3$ in the basis

Comment: I would say $\alpha^3$ = $-2\alpha$ -1. Is this correct?

Comment: yup, so what is $\alpha^4$

Comment: I just multiply by $\alpha$ and get $-2 \alpha^2 - \alpha$. If this is correct, do you know how I can get a: Find a monic polynomial g(x) of degree 3 in F[x] such that $α^2$ is a zero of g(x).

Comment: Yup, or equivalently $\alpha^2+2\alpha$. For the second qn just let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the of the cubic and run vieta to find the elementary symmetric polynomial over $\alpha^2,\beta^2,\gamma^2$